# piecewise parameterization

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

Let $C$ be the curve which connects (0,0) and (1,1) along $y^2=x^3$, the straight line from (1,1) to (0,2) and the semi circle with radius 1 and center (0,1) which connects (0,2) and (0,0)

[image]

So I drew this at first. So I think the curve is **closed** and only **piecewise smooth**. would this be correct?

Now I need the **parameterization**
What I have until now

$\phi(t)=\begin{cases} 
<t, \sqrt{t^3}> \hspace{0.5cm} 0\leq t \leq 1 \\
<2-t, t> \hspace{0.5cm} 1\leq t \leq 2 \\
....
\end{cases}$

but how to do the circle part?

the equation of the full circle would be
$x^2+(y-1)^2=1$

I tried:
$y=t$ and then
$x^2 = 1-(t-1)^2$

$x=-\sqrt{1-(t-1)^2}$ since we are in the second quadrant, we would be having the minus in front?) but what would the boundaries be ? $(1-t)^2$ has be to smaller than 1.

I also tried it with trig functions,

I have $<cost, sint+1>$ for $t \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ . would this be right?

I further need to determine whether the curve has a tangential vector in (0,0). Could please someone help me here?

Comment: There’s two nice ways to parameterize it, you can try using sines and cosines, or try $t=y$ and solve for $x$

Comment: @Snacc: thanks, i actually I had already tried this before, I now edited my post, but I do not know whether my approach is right?

Comment: You don't like trig functions?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I tried it now, I edited my post,  I would have $<cost, sint+1>$ for $t \in [\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ . would this be right?

Comment: Yes. The only thing is to fit it with the other pieces, so I suppose you want $t$ to start at $2$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks for getting back to me. I know what I am supposed to do, however I am having difficulties doing the shift for the trig function. Could you help me please?

Comment: Just shift your interval over by adding a constant to $t$? You want $t=2$ to turn into the original $t=\pi/2$, so what do you do?

Comment: @TedShifrin: I tried something,  $<cos(t*\frac{\pi}{4}), sin(t*\frac{\pi}{4})+1>$ for $t \in [2, 6]$. would this work?

Comment: Sure, that works great!

Comment: @TedShifrin: Professor Shifrin, I wanted to thank you! because thanks to you I understand the concept of piecewise parameterization really well now and how to set up the the intervals each time.

Comment: Good, Parinn. To be honest, I don't usually bother. I just parametrize them separately and add the three (or however many) integrals :P